# Convert gamlss object to lme?

Tags: r, linear-regression, nlme, gamlss

I have a continuous response with three categorical variables, no random effects. I have fit a gamlss object using the zero-adjusted gamma distribution. Link to data [here](https://universitytasmania-my.sharepoint.com/:x:/g/personal/tormey_reimer_utas_edu_au/EffXPch_97ZCkhHxd9Y9K5oBlCa1-VourhOjJqb-mjLqcA?e=fn1mVH) because it's large. I've can't get the data into a more standard distribution and I'd like to avoid using a hurdle-type analysis approach if possible for easier interpretation.

```
data_1 <- read.csv('data_1.csv', sep = ',')
library(gamlss)
mZAGA <- gamlss(cent ~ treat * cat * season, family = ZAGA(), data = data_1)
```

I want to compare the significance of the main effecs and interactions within the model, which is not a feature directly available in `gamlss` it seems. This paper describes converting a `gamlss` object into an `nlme::lme` object (https://arxiv.org/abs/1810.03085, page 17) which seems like a good approach, since `lme` models are more widely accepted by stats packages.

> Once the mixed GAMLSS is fitted and stored in an R object, the function
> `getSmo()` can be used to transform it to an `lme` object, so that all methods used with mixed
> models fitted via `lme()` become available, such as analysis of variance via the `anova()` function.

However the `getSmo` documentation isn't helping me with this conversion and trial-and-erroring is getting me nowhere. How can I use my coefficients (mu's, sigma and nu) to build an lme object? Is this something I can even do while retaining the zero-adjusted gamma distribution from `gamlss`?

Answer (score -1):

If you have no random effects, why are you using lme?

You can apply backward elimination from your model for mu:
treat * cat * season, and then from
(treat+cat+season)**2
in gamlss.

See Chapter 11: Model selection techniques, pages 377-415, in
'Flexible Regression and Smoothing: Using GAMLSS in R’
M. D. Stasinopoulos, R. A. Rigby, G. Z. Heller, V. Voudouris and F. De Bastiani.
Chapman and Hall/CRC, Boca Raton, 2017

Paperback (2020):
[www.routledge.com/9781138197909](http://www.routledge.com/9781138197909)

Note that in a zero adjusted gamma distribution, Y ~ ZAGA(mu, sigma,nu),
in gamlss,
Y has value 0 with probability nu, and
Y ~ GA(mu, sigma) with probability (1-nu).

See page 455 and also Chapter 9: Mixed Distributions (pages 177 - 206) of

‘Distributions for Modeling Location, Scale, and Shape: Using GAMLSS in R’
R. A. Rigby, M. D. Stasinopoulos, G. Z. Heller and F. De Bastiani.
Chapman and Hall/CRC, Boca Raton, 2019

Paperback (2021)
[www.routledge.com//9780367278847](http://www.routledge.com//9780367278847)

In your gamlss model, you are just modelling mu.